# How to use base URL inside number and character in PHP?

Tags: php, html, string, codeigniter, base-url

I have base URL which is `http://localhost/test/`. I have an anchor tag called as `Click me`. I checked in view source It is displaying like

```
`<a href='http://localhost/test/abdah.0`p)dp'>Click me</a>`
```

It should be displayed like

```
`<a href='http://localhost/test/index.php/example/index/4&action=print'>Click me</a>`
```

I tried code but is it not working.

```
<?php
      $session_stud_id=4;
      $bg_url='index.php/example/index/'.$session_stud_id;
      $action_url="action=print"; 
      echo $main_url=$bg_url&$action_url;//output abdah.0`p)dp 
      ?>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url($main_url);?>" >Click me</a>
```

I am getting some garbage value something like this `abdah.0`p)dp`.
Would you help me out in this?

Comment: `$bg_url&$action_url`....???.... you meant `$bg_url . "&". $action_url`

Comment: `$bg_url&$action_url` this should be like this `$bg_url.'&'.$action_url`, I guess, isnt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate multiple string using `.`
change your main_url to :

```
echo $main_url=$bg_url."&".$action_url;
```

Comment: That's correct. I forgot to concatenate multiple string. Thanks for the help it working.Upvote for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

you are not concatenating string properly on this line

`$main_url=$bg_url&$action_url;`

it shoul be  like this

`$main_url=$bg_url . "&" . $action_url;`

Comment: Thanks, @Rafail, Your code is also working. upvote from my side.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the [PHP bitwise AND operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). As per that manual page, when you use this in conjunction with strings:

> If both operands for the &, | and ^ operators are strings, then the operation will be performed on the ASCII values of the characters that make up the strings and the result will be a string. In all other cases, both operands will be converted to integers and the result will be an integer.

So your two strings `index.php/example/index/` and `action=print` are being evaulated like this, character by character. For the first characters:

```
Char Ascii Binary
a    97    1100001
i    105   1101001
```

These binary values are evaulated like so:

```
  1100001
  1101001
& 1100001
```

In this case we end up back with the value 97, which equates back to `a`, which is shown in your final string. For the values after the length of the shorter string, the values are evaluated against zero, which results in no character being added.

You probably want to use

```
$main_url = "{$bg_url}?{$action_url}";
echo $main_url;
```

(Other answers have mentioned just concatenating with `&`, but since your `$bg_url` doesn't have an existing query-string, I think you probably need to use `?`)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. Now I understand it. upvote from my side.